# Ways to prepare statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am new to use mysql with JAVA API.  Now the way I send query or update is that I simply create a String containing all lines, and then pass it to executeQuery() or executeUpdate(). I found it annoy because to pass variables from Java I would have to end quote put in variable another quote, and I had to work carefully around spaces and inner quotes.

I was wondering:

1. Is there a better way to send queries or updates? I tried to do some research on reasons for PreparedStatement but didn't learn much.
2. Is there a better way to pass variables?

Also, if you have got some advice for newbies please also include it. 
Thanks

Comment: `I tried to do some research on reasons for PreparedStatement but didn't learn much.` - keep looking, that is the way to go. There are examples in the forum or on the web. For example did you look at the posting under the `Related` heading on the right side of this page? We can't guess what you find confusing about the examples you have already found.

Comment: [Example of `PreparedStatement` for insert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11441591/1065197) Hint: you can do similar for `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `SELECT` statements.

Comment: And [just another example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15122018/1065197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Prepared statement method should work fine.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
Stirng studentUpdate = "UPDATE student SET grade = ? where id = ?";
try {
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(studentUpdate);
    pstmt.setString(1, "A");
    pstmt.setInt(2, 34);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();

} catch(Exception a) {
    a.printStackTrace();
}
```

Option 2: Create a stored procedure in your database 
[The java stored Procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html) talks extensively about this (I used it when I had single quote problems (') with my strings ).

Comment: "Option 2" really includes "Option 1", because you'd want to use a `PreparedStatement` to pass parameters to your stored procedures.

Comment: Yes that's right. you would have to use Stored Procedures for both. I should mention that option 2 would just pass the values to DB where the logic is stored. and option 1 would pass the statement it's self.